# Firebase Realtime Database - Map Live Data to List View

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Child Event Listener that logs when a new child is added:

```
override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
Log.d("TAG", p0.child("name").getValue(String::class.java) + "/" + p0.child("telephone").getValue(String::class.java))
}
```

It produces the following in my Logcat:

```
D/TAG: John/123456
D/TAG: Lisa/12345688
D/TAG: Jeremy/999
```

I'm now trying to display these live results within a List View on my Main Activity:

[image]

I've never done this before. I've started the process but could use some assistance getting it to work.

I am getting all sorts of errors using some code I found online:

[image]

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mListView: ListView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.lv_show_users)

        val UserList = mDatabase.child("Users")

        val listItems = arrayOfNulls<String>(UserList.size)

        for (i in 0 until UserList.size) {
            val user = UserList[i]
            listItems[i] = user.name
        }

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, listItems)

        mListView.adapter = adapter

        val childEventListener = object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                Log.d("TAG", p0.child("name").getValue(String::class.java) + "/" + p0.child("telephone").getValue(String::class.java))
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        }

        mDatabase.child("Users").addChildEventListener(childEventListener)

        bt_add_user.setOnClickListener {

            val name = et_user_name.text.toString().trim()
            val telephone = et_user_telephone.text.toString().trim()

            writeNewUser(name, telephone)
        }

    }

    private fun writeNewUser(name: String, telephone: String) {
        val user = Users(name, telephone)
        mDatabase.child("Users").push().setValue(user)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_user_name"
        android:hint="Name"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_user_telephone"
        android:hint="Telephone"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bt_add_user"
        android:text="Add User"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv_show_users"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't work:

```
val UserList = mDatabase.child("Users")

val listItems = arrayOfNulls<String>(UserList.size)
```

The first line merely defines a *reference* to a location in the database. It doesn't read any data yet.

That means that the `UserList.size` doesn't exist, as no data has been loaded yet. You can also see that when you look at the [documentation for `DatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference), which does not contain a `size` method/property.

The normal way to deal with this, is to define the list as empty at the start, and then add user names as you get them back from the database.

Comment: Ok, understood... Let me have a fiddle with it.